# How do I scrape multiple table rows from this url using scrapy?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

```
import scrapy

class SsoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'sso'
    allowed_domains = ['www.sso.agc.gov.sg']
    start_urls = ['https://sso.agc.gov.sg/Browse/Act/Current']

def parse(self, response):
    acts = response.xpath("//table[@class='table browse-list']/tbody")

    for act in acts:
        yield {
            #'Act title': act.xpath(".//tr[@class='alternate']/td/a/text()").get(),
            'Act title': act.xpath(".//tr/td/a/text()").get(),
            #'Short-hand code': act.xpath(".//tr[@class='alternate']/td/a/@href").get()
            'Short-hand code': act.xpath(".//tr/td/a/@href").get()
        }
```

So this is my code above for scraping. After running it, I only get 1 scraped result.
[image]

I think the issue got to do with how the table rows are created? Like some has class while some does not.
[image]

I'm new to scraping so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try this I hope it will work.

```
import scrapy

class SsoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'sso'
    allowed_domains = ['www.sso.agc.gov.sg']
    start_urls = ['https://sso.agc.gov.sg/Browse/Act/Current']

def parse(self, response):
    acts = response.xpath("//*[@id='listPanel']/table/tbody/tr")
    for act in acts:
        yield {
            'Act title': act.xpath("td[1]/a/text()").extract_first(),
            'Short-hand code': act.xpath("td/a/@href").extract_first()
        }
```

Let me know.